# How to run commands in windows docker file with a space in the path

Tags: windows, docker, cmd, dockerfile

Let's say I have a folder and I want to see what is inside it, i can do this on linux:

```
RUN ls ./path
```

and on windows I would do this:

```
RUN dir C:/Program Files (x86)
```

O wait.. that doesn't work.. (thanks windows!)

So how do I run the dir command on a path that has a space in it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Answering my own question, use this syntax

```
RUN (dir "C:/Program Files (x86)")
```

putting the () around the command preserves all spaces.

Comment: __DIR__ is an internal command of `cmd.exe`. The usage help output on running `cmd /?` in a [command prompt](https://www.howtogeek.com/235101/) window explains the command line options also file (and folder) name completion and in last paragraph on last help page also that a file name (or a folder name or any other argument string) containing a space or one of these characters ``&()[]{}^=;!'+,`~`` must be enclosed in `"`. So your superb answer is nothing new for any user of Windows Command Processor who has ever reads its usage help.

Comment: I recommend to try out once also the file/folder name completion feature by entering in the command prompt window `C:\pro` and press slowly multiple times the key __TAB__. There can be seen how `cmd` searches for file system entries matching input string. There is displayed `"C:\Program Files"` (note the backslash and the double quotes) and next `"C:\Program Files (x86)"` and next `C:\ProgramData` (no double quotes!) and then most likely again `"C:\Program Files"`. Continue typing `\Int` resulting in the display of `"C:\Program Files"\Int` and press again the key __TAB__.

Comment: There is `"` in the middle of the argument string before pressing __TAB__, but displayed is now most likely `"C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer"`. There can be seen that `"` in the middle is moved to the end of the folder path (argument string). The directory separator is ``\`` on Windows and not `/` as on Linux/Mac. The Microsoft documentation about [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file) explains how the Windows file I/O functions handle a file/folder string containing `/` (replace them by ``\``).

Comment: But the usage of `/` as directory separator on Windows can nevertheless result in unexpected and not working behavior because of `cmd.exe` itself does in some use cases not interpret `/` as directory separator. Run in a command prompt window `for %I in (C:/Windows/*.exe) do @if not exist "%I" (echo File "%I" does not exist!) else echo Found file "%I"` (no file found by __FOR__ does exist!) and run next `for %I in (C:\Windows\*.exe) do @if not exist "%I" (echo File "%I" does not exist!) else echo Found file "%I"`. Two characters different in a path and the result is completely different!

Comment: BTW: The Linux/Mac shell interpreters require enclosing a folder path containing a space also in `"` or in `'` (type of quote defines further processing of the argument string by the shell interpreter) as also the shell interpreters handle a space character in a not quoted argument string as argument separator like the Windows Command Processor.